# Having 2 problems in these codes

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Error 1) `mysql_query(): Unknown column 'steamprofile' in 'field list' on line 9`

Error 2) `mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given on line 10`.

```
<?php  (LINE 1)
$sitename = "www.xxx.com"; (LINE 2)
$link = mysql_connect("ip", "root", "password"); (LINE 3)
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('database', $link); (LINE 4)
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); (LINE 5)

function fetchinfo($rowname,$tablename,$finder,$findervalue) { (LINE 7)
    if($finder == "1") $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename"); (LINE 8)
    else $result = mysql_query("SELECT $rowname FROM $tablename WHERE `$finder`='$findervalue'"); (LINE 9)
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result); (LINE 10)
    return $row[$rowname];  (LINE 11)
}
?>
```

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: **STOP** using deprecated `mysql_*` API . Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Comment: Looks like your table has no column `steamprofile` or your tablename is wrong.

Comment: When i use mysqli, it just gives me more error :/

Comment: Then your migration is not completely right.

Comment: Can you please explain further? I'm really new in all these, this is a code i bought that's supposedly to be error-free. But, there's a few errors in there, i managed to fix a few. But there's just 3-4 errors left that i'm unable to fix:/

Comment: We can not help you without seeing the errors. Also you should read some tutorials. This wil help you